# Bugzilla send email to unregistered users on updated issues

Tags: bugzilla

Is it possible to have emails of interested parties beeing used in Bugzilla when issues are updated instead of just registered users emails like assigne etc?
The idea here is to build a front end that makes it possible for users to register "tickets" that in the background create a Bugzilla issue. I would then like the person registering the ticket to be able to provide his email address and recive updates about the issue without having to create a Bugzilla user for that person. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that this is possible. My initial thought was "Just CC them with their email address", but looking at the `cc` table in the bugzilla schema (3.6.x) reveals:

```
bugs=# \d cc
  Table "public.cc"
  Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
 --------+---------+-----------
  bug_id | integer | not null
  who    | integer | not null
 ...
 "fk_cc_who_profiles_userid" FOREIGN KEY (who) REFERENCES profiles(userid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This means that CC'd people need to be part of the `profiles` table.

Then again, if the users only ever see the front end, why not create a bugzilla profile for their email address as well and CC them on the bug? Just make sure that your email template (which you can customize) doesn't contain links to the real bugzilla instance.